# Lexer for a Scheme-like language in rust

Tags: parsing, rust, lexical-analysis

I was/am working on an interpreter for a scheme-like language. Just some time back I shifted my implementation from C++ to Rust, which I just started learning. I know there are parser libraries like LALRPROP and nom in Rust that could parse easily for me, but I wanted to try and write it in Rust from scratch. Any comments and help would be much appreciated so that I can write more idiomatic Rust.

`object.rs`: has the definition of the AST and functions for display and conversion of the AST to strings.

```rust
use crate::util;
use std::fmt;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Object {
    Integer(i64),
    Boolean(bool),
    Character(char),
    String(String),
    Symbol(String),
    Cons { car: Box<Object>, cdr: Box<Object> },
    Nil,
}

pub type ObjectBox = Box<Object>;

pub mod constants {
    use super::Object;
    pub const TRUE: Object = Object::Boolean(true);
    pub const FALSE: Object = Object::Boolean(false);
    pub const NIL: Object = Object::Nil;
}

impl Object {
    fn pair_to_string(&self) -> String {
        let mut result = String::from("");
        if let Object::Cons { car, cdr } = &*self {
            result.push_str(&car.to_string());
            match **cdr {
                Object::Cons { car: _, cdr: _ } => {
                    result.push(' ');
                    result.push_str(&cdr.pair_to_string());
                }
                Object::Nil => result.push_str(""),
                _ => {
                    result.push_str(" . ");
                    result.push_str(&cdr.to_string());
                }
            };
            return result;
        } else {
            panic!("I shouldnt be here!");
        }
    }

    pub fn to_string(&self) -> String {
        match &*self {
            Object::Integer(i) => i.to_string(),
            Object::Boolean(i) => {
                if *i {
                    "#t".to_string()
                } else {
                    "#f".to_string()
                }
            }
            Object::Character(i) => match i {
                '\n' => "$\\n".to_string(),
                '\t' => "$\\t".to_string(),
                '\r' => "$\\r".to_string(),
                '\0' => "$\\0".to_string(),
                '\\' => "$\\\\".to_string(),
                ' ' => "$space".to_string(),
                _ => format!("${}", i),
            },
            Object::String(i) => format!("\"{}\"", util::raw_string(i)),
            Object::Symbol(i) => i.to_string(),
            cons @ Object::Cons { car: _, cdr: _ } => format!("({})", cons.pair_to_string()),
            Object::Nil => "()".to_string(),
        }
    }
}

impl fmt::Display for Object {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", self.to_string())
    }
}
```

`parser.rs`: The parser, it tokenizes and parses at the same time. Meaningfull error messages still need to be added, I am planning on making a custom error type, so i can also pass the error position.

```rust
use super::object::*;

pub struct Parser<'a> {
    source: &'a str,
    start: usize,
    current: usize,
}

impl<'a> Parser<'a> {
    pub fn new(source: &'a str) -> Self {
        Parser {
            source: source,
            start: 0,
            current: 0,
        }
    }

    pub fn set_source(&mut self, new_source: &'a str) {
        self.source = new_source;
    }

    fn is_at_end(&self) -> bool {
        self.current - 1 == self.source.chars().count()
    }

    fn advance(&mut self) -> Option<char> {
        self.current += 1;
        self.source.chars().nth(self.current - 1)
    }

    fn peek(&self) -> Option<char> {
        self.source.chars().nth(self.current)
    }

    fn is_delimiter(&self, ch: char) -> bool {
        ch.is_ascii_whitespace() || matches!(ch, '(' | ')' | ';' | '"' | '\'') || self.is_at_end()
    }

    fn peek_delimiter(&self) -> bool {
        if let Some(ch) = self.peek() {
            self.is_delimiter(ch)
        } else {
            true
        }
    }

    fn is_symbol_initial(&self, ch: char) -> bool {
        !matches!(ch, '(' | ')' | ';' | '$' | '#' | '"' | '-' | '\'') && !ch.is_ascii_digit()
    }

    fn is_symbol_character(&self, ch: char) -> bool {
        !matches!(ch, '(' | ')' | ';' | '\'') || ch.is_ascii_whitespace()
    }

    fn skip_whitespace(&mut self) {
        while let Some(ch) = self.peek() {
            if ch.is_whitespace() {
                self.advance();
                continue;
            } else if ch == ';' {
                while let Some(ch) = self.advance() {
                    if ch == '\n' {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                continue;
            }

            break;
        }
    }

    fn peek_number(&self, ch: char) -> bool {
        ch.is_ascii_digit() || (ch == '-' && self.peek().unwrap().is_ascii_digit())
    }

    fn parse_number(&mut self) -> Result<ObjectBox, String> {
        while let Some(ch) = self.peek() {
            if ch.is_ascii_digit() {
                self.advance();
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        Ok(ObjectBox::new(Object::Integer(
            self.source
                .chars()
                .skip(self.start)
                .take(self.current - self.start)
                .collect::<String>()
                .parse::<i64>()
                .unwrap(),
        )))
    }

    fn parse_boolean(&mut self) -> Result<ObjectBox, String> {
        if let Some(ch) = self.advance() {
            match ch {
                't' => Ok(ObjectBox::new(constants::TRUE)),
                'f' => Ok(ObjectBox::new(constants::FALSE)),
                _ => Err(String::from("")),
            }
        } else {
            Err(String::from(""))
        }
    }

    fn parse_character(&mut self) -> Result<ObjectBox, String> {
        // TODO: Add $\x80 and $\d97 style characters
        if let Some(ch) = self.advance() {
            if ch == '\\' {
                if let Some(ch) = self.advance() {
                    if !self.peek_delimiter() {
                        return Err(String::from(""));
                    }
                    match ch {
                        'n' => return Ok(ObjectBox::new(Object::Character('\n'))),
                        'r' => return Ok(ObjectBox::new(Object::Character('\r'))),
                        't' => return Ok(ObjectBox::new(Object::Character('\t'))),
                        '\\' => return Ok(ObjectBox::new(Object::Character('\\'))),
                        '0' => return Ok(ObjectBox::new(Object::Character('\0'))),
                        ' ' => return Ok(ObjectBox::new(Object::Character(' '))),
                        _ => return Err(String::from("")),
                    }
                } else {
                    return Err(String::from(""));
                }
            } else {
                if !self.peek_delimiter() {
                    return Err(String::from(""));
                }
                return Ok(ObjectBox::new(Object::Character(ch)));
            }
        } else {
            return Err(String::from(""));
        }
    }

    fn parse_string(&mut self) -> Result<ObjectBox, String> {
        let mut result = String::new();

        while let Some(ch) = self.advance() {
            if self.is_at_end() {
                return Err(String::from("at end"));
            }

            if ch == '"' {
                return Ok(ObjectBox::new(Object::String(result)));
            }

            if ch == '\\' {
                if let Some(ch) = self.advance() {
                    match ch {
                        'n' => result.push('\n'),
                        'r' => result.push('\r'),
                        't' => result.push('\t'),
                        '\\' => result.push('\\'),
                        '0' => result.push('\0'),
                        _ => result.push(ch),
                    }

                    continue;
                } else {
                    return Err(String::from("empty escape sequence"));
                }
            }

            result.push(ch);
        }

        Err(String::from("no ending quote"))
    }

    fn parse_pair(&mut self) -> Result<ObjectBox, String> {
        let car: ObjectBox;
        let cdr: ObjectBox;
        self.skip_whitespace();
        if let Some(ch) = self.peek() {
            if ch == ')' {
                self.advance();
                return Ok(ObjectBox::new(constants::NIL));
            }

            match self.parse() {
                Ok(object_box) => car = object_box,
                a @ Err(_) => return a,
            }

            self.skip_whitespace();

            if let Some(ch) = self.peek() {
                if ch == '.' {
                    self.advance();

                    if !self.peek_delimiter() {
                        return Err(String::from(""));
                    }

                    match self.parse() {
                        Ok(object_box) => cdr = object_box,
                        a @ Err(_) => return a,
                    }

                    self.skip_whitespace();

                    if let Some(ch) = self.advance() {
                        if ch == ')' {
                            return Ok(ObjectBox::new(Object::Cons { car, cdr }));
                        } else {
                            return Err(String::from(""));
                        }
                    } else {
                        return Err(String::from(""));
                    }
                } else {
                    match self.parse_pair() {
                        Ok(object_box) => cdr = object_box,
                        a @ Err(_) => return a,
                    }

                    return Ok(ObjectBox::new(Object::Cons { car, cdr }));
                }
            }
        }
        Err(String::from("here"))
    }

    fn parse_symbol(&mut self) -> Result<ObjectBox, String> {
        while let Some(ch) = self.peek() {
            if self.is_symbol_character(ch) {
                self.advance();
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        return Ok(ObjectBox::new(Object::Symbol(
            self.source
                .chars()
                .skip(self.start)
                .take(self.current - self.start)
                .collect::<String>(),
        )));
    }

    pub fn parse(&mut self) -> Result<ObjectBox, String> {
        self.skip_whitespace();
        self.start = self.current;

        let ch = self.advance().unwrap();

        match ch {
            ch if self.peek_number(ch) => self.parse_number(),
            '#' => self.parse_boolean(),
            '$' => self.parse_character(),
            '"' => self.parse_string(),
            '(' => self.parse_pair(),
            ch if self.is_symbol_initial(ch) => self.parse_symbol(),
            _ => Err(String::from("Unknown Character")),
        }
    }
}
```

`util.rs`: a utility module, for now just has a function that converts strings like `"Hello \n World!"` to `"Hello \\n World"`

```rust
pub fn raw_string(string: &str) -> String {
    let mut result = String::from("");

    for ch in string.chars() {
        match ch {
            '\n' => result.push_str("\\n"),
            '\t' => result.push_str("\\t"),
            '\r' => result.push_str("\\r"),
            '\\' => result.push_str("\\\\"),
            '\0' => result.push_str("\\0"),
            _ => result.push(ch),
        }
    }
    result
}
```

`main.rs`: The driver code, for now I am hard coding the input, the plan is to make a interactive REPL.

```rust
#![allow(dead_code)]
mod core;
mod util;

use self::core::parser::*;

fn main() {
    let mut scanner = Parser::new("\"Hello \\nWorld\"");
    match scanner.parse() {
        Ok(object) => println!("{}", object),
        Err(message) => println!("{}", message),
    }
}
```

Any tips to make the code more Rust-like will be very helpful!

Comment: So we can compile the code -- what's your `util.rs`?

Comment: Looks like you have a `core` directory defining a module (`mod.rs`) and a `util.rs` at the top level.

Comment: I put in a dummy implementation of `pub fn raw_string(i: &str) -> String` and it compiles now. :) Reviewing your code now!

Comment: @6005 Thanks for pointing out the missing util file! I am adding it to my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Clippy

First, **always, always** run `cargo clippy`. Clippy gives you lots of helpful tips to make your code more idiomatic and simpler, and sometimes catches more serious missteps. From Clippy:

- Lots of unnecessary `return` statements. To return a value on the last line of a function (or the last line of each if branch), in Rust it is preferred to omit the return statement. In your case, the biggest offender is `fn parse_character` where Clippy finds that most of your `return`s can be omitted (however, I would note that this function honestly looks pretty gnarly regardless and should be broken up into simpler more understandable functions).
- In constructing a `struct`, you can use the field name directly if it matches the local variable name: `Parser { source, start: 0, current: 0 }`
- Finally, Clippy finds a potentially more serious problem, and links you to [this page](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#inherent_to_string_shadow_display): the problem is that `.to_string()` is automatically implemented for any type that implements Display (via the [ToString](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/trait.ToString.html) trait), so there are actually two definitions of `.to_string()` for your struct, one of them being overwritten. Easiest fix is to rename your public `pub fn to_string(&self) -> String` to a private function like `fn to_string_core(&self) -> String` and use it only internally. More idiomatic fix would be to put this logic directly in the `Display` implementation and omit `to_string_core`.

That's all for Clippy fixes. Other than what Clippy finds, your code is generally pretty good, though a bit complicated in places (but this is maybe to be expected with parsing code).

### Additional comments

#### In `object.rs`:

The function `fn pair_to_string` is undesirable: it has an unstated precondition, namely that the object is a `Cons` case, and it panics if this is not satisfied. Additionally, everywhere this is used, you actually already know that the input is a cons, so the correct design is to take as input the branches of the cons directly. Here is the improved function:

```rust
    fn pair_to_string(&self, other: &Self) -> String {
        let mut result = self.to_string();
        match other {
            Object::Cons { car, cdr } => {
                result.push(' ');
                result.push_str(&car.pair_to_string(&cdr));
            }
            Object::Nil => result.push_str(""),
            _ => {
                result.push_str(" . ");
                result.push_str(&other.to_string());
            }
        };
        result
    }
```

now the code is more self-explanatory (it's clear that it takes a pair of `Object`s and prints them), simpler, and doesn't have a hidden assumption.

In general, the `Cons` object constructor and its usage should be documented and explained: a reader unfamiliar with Scheme is highly unlikely to know what this is used for (a list vs a tree, etc.)

#### In `main.rs`:

Blanket `#![allow(dead_code)]` statements are counterproductive. If you intend `core` as a public API, the easiest fix is to do `pub mod core`. If you just temporarily want to ignore the dead code warning on `set_source`, use a method-level annotation:

```rust
    #[allow(dead_code)]
    pub fn set_source(&mut self, new_source: &'a str) {
```

#### In `parser.rs`:

The use of `self.source.chars().nth` to keep getting the nth character is problematic. Note that `.chars()` will be a *new* iterator over the `source` string each time and `nth` will get the nth character; so you probably have a very inefficient algorithm (at least n^2) for parsing large strings. There are two possible fixes here.

**First, the easy way:** Strings are a pain because character boundaries are of different lengths, making indexing into them difficult. So to completely avoid string issues, get rid of `&str` in the beginning and instead convert it to an array of characters: `&[char]`. Converting a string `s` to a vector of characters is easy: `let char_vec: Vec<char> = s.chars().collect()`. Then use `&char_vec` to get a `&[char]`.

**The harder way:** to work with the string directly, what you "really" want is a pointer into the string, not an index. So `start` and `current` should really be iterators with lifetime `&'a` which are pointing into the string `source`. Like this:

```rust
use std::str::Chars;
pub struct ParserBetter<'a> {
    source: &'a str,
    start: Chars<'a>,
    current: Chars<'a>,
}
```

This will involve a more substantial code rewrite, but it might be a good learning exercise for how to properly work with strings.

The takeaway message is **don't index into strings with an integer.** If you need to index, use a vector of characters. Indexing into strings is either highly inefficient (if done with `.chars().nth(i)`) or can fall in the middle of character boundaries (if done with `[i]`).

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I didn't know `clippy` existed! Just a few more questions, Is using an iterator over strings the preferred way to index into strings, or can I get away with a vector of `chars`? How would you break up the `parse_characters` function? The reason I didn't move the functionality of `to_string` directly into the `Display` trait is because `to_string` is mutually recursive with `pair_to_string`, how do I move it to the `Display` trait?

Comment: @BhargavKulkarni I honestly recommend a vector of chars as it is easier to work with. I'm not completely sure about `parse_characters`. For the mutually recursive issue, that's fine -- one can be part of Display and one outside Display (still mutually recursive), something like `fmt_pair` for the format version of `pair_to_string`

Comment: Multiple design choices will work. Your way works as long as you rename `to_string` to `to_string_core`